# Can the value model for variables only be used together with static typing, not with dynamic typing?

Tags: reference, programming-languages, static-typing, dynamic-typing

There are [two models of variables](https://books.google.com/books?id=jM-cBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA379&dq=value%20model%20and%20reference%20model%20variables&pg=PA231#v=onepage&q=value%20model%20and%20reference%20model%20variables&f=false): the value model (e.g. variables in C) and the reference model (e.g. variables in Python).

There is also a distinction between [static typing and dynamic typing](https://books.google.com/books?id=jM-cBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA379&dq=value%20model%20and%20reference%20model%20variables&pg=PA300#v=onepage&q=dynamic%20typing&f=false).

Can the value model only be used together with static typing, not with dynamic typing?
Or how can the value model and dynamic typing work together, and maybe some example languages?

Can the reference model for variables work with either static typing or dynamic typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether all variables contain references or values is completely independent of static vs. dynamic typing.

There are dynamically typed languages with value semantics (e.g. Perl, PHP) and statically typed languages with reference semantics (e.g. Java, C# (except structs), OCaml). There are also languages where the distinction plain does not matter because there is no mutability or observable object identity (e.g. Haskell).

Comment: Thanks. Could you show that Perl or PHP use value semantics and are dynamically typed? I happen to be unfamiliar with the two languages.

Comment: Scheme is dynamically typed and uses the reference model for variables. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57403446/10082400 says "the data models of a number of modern scripting languages -- Perl, PHP, Python, and JavaScript -- appear to be inspired by the Lisp family of languages." So shouldn't PHP and Perl also are dynamically typed and uses the reference model for variables?

Comment: @Ben Here's a demonstration of Perl's value semantics: https://ideone.com/BsPTJH . And here's one of PHP's: https://ideone.com/lQgsgb . Note that from PHP 5 on, objects in PHP changed to use reference semantics, but arrays still use value semantics (as demonstrated in the linked code). As you can see, both languages also provide an explicit syntax for references in cases where you want reference semantics (as languages defaulting to value semantics generally do).